# Node: Spawn child but kill itself

Tags: node.js, auto-update, child-process

Is there a way to run a shell command like `npm start` which is completely independent of the host, so that it can kill itself?

I'm trying to develop a self-updating application with Node.js. My plan to do it is the following:

1. **[Main]** Download a seperate updater application (it's also a Node.js application)
2. **[Main]** Install dependencies of the updater with: `npm install`
3. **[Main]** Start the updater with: `npm start`
4. **[Main]** Kill itself (the main application) with: `process.exit()`
5. **[Updater]** Download new version of the main application
6. **[Updater]** Install dependencies of the main application with: `npm install`
7. **[Updater]** Start the main application again with: `npm start`
8. **[Updater]** Kill itself (the updater) with: `process.exit()`
9. **[Main]** Done.

I only know of `child_process.exec()` and `child_process.spawn()`, but these two will kill the updater too when the main application kills itself with `process.exit()`

Is this generally a bad idea, what would be a better way? If not, how can I let the updater stay alive, when killing the main application?

Comment: You need the spawned process to be detached from its parent. See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached